# Is crystaloferous real?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've heard a lot of rumors, like that people who were data mining in borderlands 2 found a 3rd invincible, other then Terramorphous and Vermivorous. This is the main game without dlc. Is this true and if so, how do you spawn it?

Answer (score 2):

There is a discussion going on on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/10pgof/has_anybody_found_the_3rd_and_presumably_final/). It seems to be nobody found it yet. 
[An other source said](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=158949&page=33#325):

> I took a deeper look at the game files by extracting all the *.upk
>   Files in Borderlands 2 > WillowGame > CookedPCConsole > and ran GNU
>   "strings" (Outputs Readable Strings out of Binaries) overall finds
>   grepping (filtering) for certain Keywords. You can find References to
>   Vermivorous and Terramorphous in the MapFiles they spawn in (Cavern_P
>   and ThresherRaid_P). I searched for BugMorphRaid (Internal name from
>   Vermi, you can get it from the corresponding LocalizationFile
>   GD_Population_BugMorph) and was able to localize it in the files for
>   all maps he can spawn. Same thing for Terra. His Map is Called
>   ThresherRaid_P which makes the whole thing a lot easier. Fun fact:
>   Filtering for "Invincible" also gives you only references to Vermi and
>   Terra. I couldn't find a Map referencing to Crystaloferous! There are
>   references to it in "RefShaderCache-PC-D3D-SM3.upk" (as there are for
>   Terra but not Vermi for some reason) but that's it. From my search I
>   unfortunately assume that Crystal is in the game but doesn't have a
>   spawn location (yet). **It either will be a DLC or it'll be patched in
>   at a later point of view.** Hopefully someone will proof me wrong, but I
>   doubt it

Comment: Could have been like how they wanted to make Roscoe to be an invincible too but changed their minds. They probably had Crystaloferous in the game at one point then scrapped him before release.

Comment: Yeah, 5 months later and still no evidence of him beyond this, I down he's currently in the game.